# Laravel5 ajax delete wouldn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I'm working on a project, where I should **delete** users from the `users` table with **ajax**. I've been seeking for multiple solutions, but it just simply wouldn't work anyhow. Here's the error I'm getting:

> *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)*.

[image: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46]

JS:

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/laravel-exercise/public/index/'+id,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

View:

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete"
 value="{{$user->id}}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">Delete</button>
```

Route:

```php
Route::delete('index/{$id}', 'UsersController@destroy');
```

UsersController:

```php
public function destroy($id)
    {
            $user = User::findOrFail($id);
            $user->delete();

            return view('pages.index')->with([
                'flash_message' => 'The user has been deleted.',
                'flash_message_important' => 'true',
            ]);
    }
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Error Internal Server- menas your ajax is working fine.... better to look at php code

Comment: Laravel log file, please.

Comment: I'm new to Laravel, if you tell me more about how to get it, I'll show it to you with pleasure.

Comment: Google, dude, Google. `app/storage/logs` - If there is no log file, make sure it is enabled: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors

Comment: Side note, make sure to mention people (use @<nameofperson>) so we get notified. I stumbled upon this again randomly and had no idea you replied.

Comment: @ThomasYates Problem solved, but thanks anyways. Now I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to show flash messages with ajax.

Comment: Make sure to enable logging anyway. Without logs you and everyone here will be shooting in the dark, luckily someone guessed correctly the first go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it's due to the CSRF protection.

Try to add the `'X-CSRF-TOKEN'` before you bind the button click.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('.btn-delete').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/laravel-exercise/public/index/'+id,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

To add the CSRF token to your request.

Have a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf) for infos about.

The route is found, otherwise i'll catch a 404 exception.

**edit**

Looking at how you made the button, you could also use a `post` request, but passing a `_method` data.

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-delete" value="{{$user->id}}"
     data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">Delete</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.btn-delete').click(function(){
    var token = $(this).data('token');
    var id = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/laravel-exercise/public/index/'+id,
        type: 'post',
        data: {_method: 'delete', _token :token},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success:', data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's the same unfortunately, anyways I've added it before also to the button link.

Comment: Nope, i mean, the error is because the csrf protection. Can you try a console.log of `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')`

Comment: Now with your latest update I got a "laravel-exercise.js:50 Uncaught ReferenceError: token is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/laravel-exercise/public/js/laravel-exercise.js:50:51)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:10315)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:8342)" error.

Comment: the code afert **edit** ? Does your button has the data-token?

Comment: I forgot the var token... But as I updated it to your edit, now its Internal Server Error again...

Comment: The laravel error shows "ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 125:
No query results for model [App\User]." now...

Comment: Ok, that's because the `FindOrFail`. There's no User with id 28, looking at your image attacched.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Now it deletes the user, but doesn't refresh the view.

Comment: It doesn't refresh the view because you have to handle it, in the `success` function of your ajax call

Comment: I thought it's enought if I return the view again from the destroy function. Can you please tell me some more hints about what do I have to do now, I'm pretty new to ajax...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128614/discussion-between-giuserv-and-sklrboy).